# Some error in publishing web Services

Tags: java

```
IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer

IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseSerializerFactory.getSpecialized(BaseSerializerFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseSerializerFactory.getSerializerAsInternal(BaseSerializerFactory.java:91)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseSerializerFactory.getSerializerAs(BaseSerializerFactory.java:82)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.getSerializerAs(BeanSerializerFactory.java:64)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Types.makeTypeElement(Types.java:1838)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Types.writeTypeForPart(Types.java:421)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Types.writeTypeAndSubTypeForPart(Types.java:442)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.writePartToMessage(Emitter.java:1890)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.writeRequestMessage(Emitter.java:1486)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.writeMessages(Emitter.java:1106)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.writePortType(Emitter.java:1075)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.getWSDL(Emitter.java:484)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:331)
at org.apache.axis.wsdl.fromJava.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:430)
at org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Java2WsdlAntTask.execute(Java2WsdlAntTask.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.core.command.Java2WSDLCommand.executeAntTask(Java2WSDLCommand.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.consumption.core.command.Java2WSDLCommand.execute(Java2WSDLCommand.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.creation.ui.command.BUCodeGenOperation$BottomUpWSModifyOperation.execute(BUCodeGenOperation.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.axis.creation.ui.command.BUCodeGenOperation.execute(BUCodeGenOperation.java:86)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand
```

Comment: Psychic debugging skills have inferred that you are using Java2WSDL. It would help if you posted the source code causing this issue.

Comment: Agreed. Some error in generating WSDL from Java.

Comment: Please try your best in helping the guys who are trying to help you! Like adding at least a bit of context etc.

Comment: @Enno : I m really sry 4 that. I m new to this. I will take care of this from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeanSerializer` implements `Serializer` so we expect, that a `BeanSerializer` instance is castable to `Serializer`. Obviously that doesn't work in this case.

A common cause: two different implementations of axis have been loaded by different classloaders. Try to remove as many axis libraries as possible from your projects classpath(s), some library might interfere with the eclipse internal version of axis.

Comment: I am unable to find that. Can u help, pls